# The grammatical function of ''just so''

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, idioms

**I didn't do it just so my land could be invaded.**

How to understand the structure of this sentence?
I check the dictionary, it says 'just so' can be used as a adverb idiom, meaning 'in a particular way'.

So which is the correct structure?

1. the main clause is '**I didn't do it just so**',
   the subordinate clause is '**my land could be invaded**'.('just so' acts as adverb, 'that' acts as conjunction which is omitted)
2. the main clause is '**I didn't do it**', the subordinate clause is '**just so my land could be invaded**'. ('just so' acts as conjunction)

Comment: No: "just so" is neither an adverb  nor a conjunction. . In modern grammar "so" is a preposition, and "just" is a focusing modifier that is modifying the whole PP "(just) so my land could be invaded". I've posted an answer which may help.

Comment: @BillJ There is no entry in my dictionary for "just" as a preposition.  Neither is there for "so."

Comment: @Biblasia I didn't say that "just" is a preposition: I said it's a focusing modifier (i.e. an **adverb**). "So" is a prep in modern grammar, but most dictionaries are slow to catch up. For those who still treat "so" as a conjunction, then "so my land could be invaded" is a subordinate clause modified by the focusing adverb "just".

Comment: @BillJ _As I see it...._  The clause "my land could be invaded" is indeed a subordinate clause, mediated by the omitted _that_, which is implied. For example, in "you know I'm right," the "I'm right" is a dependent clause mediated by the omitted "that."  In the OP's sentence, "just so" adds a causative sense to "that," nearly equivalent to "_in order_ to," in meaning, but differing grammatically.  One cannot properly say "... _in order to_ my land could be invaded."  That would demonstrate prepositional usage, whereas this is clearly conjunctive instead, using "that" in place of "to."

Comment: An alternant to "so" is "in order + subordinate clause, where "in order" is a complex preposition and the subordinator "that" is here obligatory in the subordinate clause. The focusing modifier "just" can be added in either case, where the meaning is "solely".

Comment: @Date1: I suspect your example sentence doesn't mean what you think it does. Normally, the construction *I didn't do X just so Y [would happen]* very strongly implies that my ***primary*** reason for doing X was indeed to cause Y [to happen] - but it also asserts that *I had some **other** (secondary, **additional**) reason for doing X*. So your example effectively means *My **main** reason for doing it was so my land could be invaded, but that wasn't the **only** reason I did it*. Maybe that's actually what you meant to say, but I kinda doubt it.

Comment: ...there's the "sarcastic" usage of, for example, *I didn't buy you a new car just so you could crash it*, which effectively means *If I'd known you were going to crash it, I'd never have bought you the car*. But whatever "it" is in your example, it doesn't naturally strike me as a suitable context for that type or sarcasm (which is usually reserved for complaining to someone that they have carelessly trashed some benefit you went to considerable trouble to provide).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The context is like this.There are one Kingdom and one Empire. One lord of the Kingdom defects to the Empire, so the King plans on attacking this lord. But the Empire didnt really come to the lord's rescue. That's when the lord said this. But i did some changes, making the sentence shorter, the full sentence is 'I didn't do this just so my land could be leveled by the king's fiery wrath.' So i guess if the lord had known his land would be invaded, he'd never have defected?(the lord plan to invade kingdom with Empire before kingdom knows their movement, somehow the plan is leaked

Comment: All that context doesn't change the basic fact that from my perspective that use of "sarcastic" ***just so*** only really works when vociferously complaining that someone has thoughtlessly devalued / negated some "boon" you made available to them. Your king isn't exactly remonstrating with "the Empire" for having carelessly "trashed" his "gift", so your example doesn't work for me. Maybe others feel different, but that's the way ***I*** see it.

Comment: ...my preferred phrasing would therefore be more along the lines of *I'd **never have done it if I'd known** my land would be invaded.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I didn't do it* [*just so my land could be invaded*].

"Just so" is not a constituent, not a grammatical unit, so it has no function as such.

The main clause here is the matrix clause, i.e. the whole sentence.

Traditional grammar treats "so" as a conjunction, but modern grammar classifies it as a preposition, therefore "so my land could be invaded" is a preposition phrase headed by "so" with the declarative content clause "my land could be invaded" as its complement.

The focusing adverb "just" modifies the PP which then serves as a purpose adjunct in clause structure.

The clause subordinator "that" is optional, though I would omit it.

Comment: thank u very much for ur detailed explanation. it's the first time i hear about matrix clause and so as a preposition. so 'i' as subject, 'did' as verb, 'it' as object, 'just so that my land could be invaded' as a adverbial clause. is this correct?

Comment: @Date1 Matrix clause is the usual term for a clause that contain a subordinate clause. Don't fret too much about the status of "so". It's a prep in modern grammar, but most dictionaries are slow to catch up. For those who still treat "so" as a conjunction, then "just so my land could be invaded" is a subordinate clause introduced by the conjunction "so", and modified by the focusing adverb "just". The term 'adjunct' is an alternative and better term for adverbial.

Comment: @Date1 It's important that you don't think of "just so" as a phrase. It isn't: "so" introduces the subordinate clause "so my land could be invaded",and the adverb "just" is a separate modifier that is modifying the whole clause. Is that clear? "Just" is a focusing modifier; here it means "solely".

Comment: thank u so much. i think i got it. if 'just so' acts as an idiom, is it commonly used in everyday life?

Comment: @Date1 No! Wrong meaning. The "just so" in your example is **not** an idiom as it is in "He's very fussy; he likes everything to be just so". In your example "just" and "so" are not directly connected, i.e. not a grammatical unit. "So" introduces the clause, and "just" modifies the whole clause where it means "solely" (or "only"). Is that clear now?

Answer (score -1):

If you use "just so" in the context of "in a particular way," it would take a form like this:

- He was a very meticulous person: everything had to be *just so.*

However, in the context of the example sentence provided in the question, this is not the usage.

> I didn't do it **just so** my land could be invaded.

In this case, the "just so" is equivalent to "in order that."  The speaker is saying that he or she did not take a particular action for the purpose of opening his or her land to be invaded.  Some action was taken, something was done, but there was some other reason than opening the land to invasion that had prompted that action.

Note that the word "that" is optional in the sentence, and has been omitted.  If supplied, it might make the grammar clearer.

I didn't do it *just so* **that** my land could be invaded.

Comment: Using *just* is irony. Let's add that there was **no** reason that 'I did it' and wanted my land invaded. I most certainly did not do it with that in mind, but the opposite in mind. In the sentence "I didn't get married just so you'd cheat," the **just so** does not mean *for that reason among others, but not solely* for that reason.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It may be dependent on the reader's own inference.  Without tone of voice, neither of us can be sure, but I understood "just" in this sentence in the sense of "merely" or "simply"--i.e. as if that were the only reason.  This implies there was some other motivation.

Comment: But who would have one or more reasons to want their land invaded, tone of voice or not?

Comment: @YosefBaskin  For example: Suppose the speaker had engineered the construction of railways to increase commerce within the country.  Railroads are a major tool for would-be invaders--which is exactly why trains do not cross the border between France and Spain, because the railway tracks were deliberately made with different spacings, so trains from one side could not simply invade on the other side.  Obviously, one would not build the tracks **just so** his or her country could be invaded.

Comment: thank u so much for explaining so throughly. i am a little curious about the sentence on the Merriam-Webster website 'They feel they have to dress just so to be popular.' here is the 'just so' a adverb phrase? or is it a bit too old-fashioned?

Comment: @Date1 In that example sentence, "just so" is used as in my first example, to mean "in a particular way."  You might see this more easily by rearranging the sentence.  Consider: "They feel, to be popular, they have to dress _just so_."

Comment: @Biblasia oh, i got it. is 'so' here kinda like referring to something mentioned before. Like the 'so' in 'or so i heard'(though the word class is different).

Comment: @Date1 I think when "so" is used to mean "in a particular way," it is often used with no clear reference to anything said prior.  It leaves to the hearer's imagination to infer how _carefully_ or how _specifically_ something is to be understood.  To have things done "just _so_" is to make sure they are done in a particular way...and nothing less will satisfy the requirements.  To dress "just so" might imply very _properly_ (consider a suit and tie), or it might even imply very _casually_ (e.g. shorts and a T-shirt)--whatever is considered "proper" and "fashionable" by the "popular" people.

Comment: @Biblasia okay, i got it now. 'I didn't do it just so my land could be invaded.' is the way this sentence is built commonly used in everyday life?